# Haskell: defining a roll function for a image

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Im new to Haskell and am working with images represented as `type Img = [String]`.
I want to create a function that moves the image up or down 1 or more rows.

An image example below.

```
img 1= [ "XX XX"          
       , "  X  "
       , "XX XX"
       ]
```

My goal is to write a function `moveImg :: Int -> Img -> Img` that translates the image vertically, wrapping over; e.g.:

```
 moveImg 1 (img 1) = -- Move up by 1
   [ "  X  "
   , "XX XX"  
   , "XX XX"          
   ]

 moveImg (-1) (img 1) =  -- Move down by 1
   [ "XX XX"  
   , "XX XX"     
   , "  X  "
   ]
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: @duffn - i worked with a friend who knows some haskell on this problem. He came up with -----------                                                                                             move n as = head ts : (hs ++ tail ts)
where (hs, ts) = splitAt n as ----------                                                                      but its not quiet how I want it to work.

Comment: how do you want it to work?

Comment: try to work this out: ``let transSym i xs = let l = length xs in take l $ drop (i `mod` l) (xs++xs)`` (`up` -> `i=1`, `down` -> `i=(-1)`)

Comment: is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps a more elementary approach can be

```
moveImg n xs = take len $ drop (mod n len) $ cycle xs
        where len = length xs
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that he'll just copy and paste this, and come back with another problem where here needs to do that horizontally... [OH WAIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499786/haskell-moving-image-on-horizontal-line).

Answer (score 2):

You're friend's code doesn't work because it's missing the modulo operator--so the rotation isn't "wrapping" around. Carsten's code works (his code works by stacking the list with itself and then taking the appropriate slice; it'll "wrap" because it is stacked); here's an alternative. This is just [the array rotation problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/).

```
    import Data.List (splitAt)
    import Data.Tuple (swap)



    rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]

    rotate k xs = uncurry (++) $ swap $ splitAt (k `mod` length xs) xs
```

We split the list into two halves--and we `mod` in order to enable rotation, `swap` the front for the back, and add them together. `swap` works on tuples (which `splitAt` returns). `uncurry` just forces list concatenation (`++`) to work on a tuple of rather than two separate arguments. It converts a function of type `a -> b -> c` to type `(a, b) -> c`.

Here are some tests--`forM_` is just used like a for-loop to print each line in sequence.

```
    import Control.Monad (forM_)
    main = do
      let img = ["XX XX",          
                 "  X  ",
                 "XX XX"]      
      putStrLn "Up is positive"
      forM_ (rotate 1 img) print
      putStrLn "Down is negative"
      forM_ (rotate (-1) img) print
```

Gives the following output:

```
    Up is positive
    "  X  "
    "XX XX"
    "XX XX"
    Down is negative
    "XX XX"
    "XX XX"
    "  X  "
```

If you wanted to, you could create a `Up`/`Down` data type instead of using positive/negative values. e.g.

```
    data Direction = Up | Down
    rotate :: Direction -> Int -> [String] -> [String]
    rotate d k xs = . . .
```