# Haskell: moving image on horizontal line

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Im new to Haskell and am working with images represented as `type Img = [String]`.
I want to move the image either left or right by 1 or more rows with a wrap.

i've manged to move the images up or down, code below:

```
moveVer :: Int -> Img -> Img
moveVer n xs = take len $ drop (mod n len) $ cycle xs
      where len = length xs

img 1 = XXXXXX       OUTPUT = (moveVer (3)(img 1))  = XX
          XX                                          XX
          XX                                        XXXXXX  
          XX                                        XXXXXX
        XXXXXX                                        XX
```

Now i'm trying to do the same thing but move the image horizontally (left or right).
function to defined `moveHor :: Int -> Img -> Img`

Comment: No, you haven't "managed" anything - it's a literally copy and paste from your previous question's answer. Perhaps actually understanding what you're doing is a better long-term investment.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental algorithm is the same as your vertical shift function, since `String` is also a list of characters, `[Char]`.

You can generalize your algorithm to a `move` function since the code for `moveVer` really only requires a list and has no dependency on `Img`:

```haskell
move :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
move n xs = take len $ drop (mod n len) $ cycle xs
  where len = length xs
```

Now you can rewrite your `moveVer` function in terms of `move`:

```haskell
moveVer :: Int -> Img -> Img
moveVer = move
```

And since a string is just a List of characters, you can map over the list of strings and use the `move` function to do your horizontal movement.

```haskell
moveHor :: Int -> Img -> Img
moveHor n = map $ move n
```